# A call to JRuby brings up java options menu

Tags: java, path, jruby

When I run jruby.exe on the command line or any of the other ruby executables such as `rake`, `bundle` etc., it prints the java help message (as below) as if I have simply executed `java` on the command line.

I dont know how this started to happen. As everything seemed to be operating fine on Friday. I have checked my `PATH` variable, `JRUBY_OPTS` variable and everything is setup correctly. Please if anyone understands why this is occurring and how I can rememedy this it would be greatly appreciated. I have been at it for hours with no success.

Example:

```
cmd> rake

Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
       (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
       (to execute a jar file)

where options include:
-server       to select the "server" VM
-hotspot      is a synonym for the "server" VM  [deprecated]
              The default VM is server.

-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose[:class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:<value>
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -jre-no-restrict-search
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument

-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image
```

Comment: What version of JRuby?  What platform?  Have you tried uninstall and re-install?

Comment: We are currently using jRuby 1.7.0-dev on Windows 2003 64-bit. I have tried uninstalling Jruby and java to no avail. We have been using 1.7.0 for a few weeks now and it is functioning on all other machines perfectly, except on this one machine ... it has been operating on this machine until Friday, but I cant pinpoint any changes

Comment: Any reason you cannot use JRuby 1.6.5 - the current version?

Comment: A Windows Update seems to have solved the issue. This is no longer occuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Windows Update seems to have solved the issue. This is no longer occuring.

Comment: That is great that you were able to resolve the issue. Please accept your answer to allow others to find it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Windows) I removed the trailing `/` from the end of my `JAVA_HOME` and `JRUBY_HOME` and this made jruby work. After this the  options stop printing out.